# Microsoft Word to PDF - table glitches

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I'm on Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 with default settings. Seems like tables have a lot of glitches when document is converted to PDF from Save as.

I have a requirement for 2 tables in the following formats:
[image: 2 tables]

The screenshot is taken from the converted PDF. As you can see, almost each cell has some or the other issue with borders, background or both.

Here is the formatting -
The formatting for both tables is the same. Table Row Height: 0.5 cm, Align Center, Preferred width: 100%, 2 1/4 pt border, 0.1 cm cell margins, Allow spacing between cells unchecked & Automatically resize to fit contents checked. Background color can be any color.

2nd table has some extras - D is merged 2 rows, E column is split into 3 sub-columns, F into 2 sub-columns & G is merged 2 rows.

Can someone please guide or help?
Thanks.

Comment: i can provide the doc file & pdf file... how do i upload them here?

Answer (score 0):

Tables in Word are drawn in PDF as multiple nested rectangles. Some of that requirement is for accessibility by tagging a PDF with tabular zones , since PDF has no simple native  table structure, if it did, it would make life simpler.

[image]

so the issue with overlapping edges of rectangles is they may clash in different ways especially when colour filled.

Comment: thanks for the reply @K J... i have limited technical knowledge. but i see what could be the reason for glitchy tables in pdf... i wonder though, how come many pdfs that i see have perfect tables?